# EF6 creates an extra and empty entity (table)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

There are three entities in my database (at least there should be three).
1. General Information about the offer.
2. Customer list
3. List of items in the offer.
Initially, I proceeded from the fact that there would be only one customer in the offer and everything was fine: the database had three tables in accordance with the number of entities. But now I have a list of customers in the offer and a property to indicate who placed this one. This caused the appearance of a 4th table called "ProcurementDataCustomers". The table is empty, meaning that after parsing and filling in the data in other tables, it remains so. How can I make it so that when creating a database it does not automatically create this table? Is there any way to control this process?

### ProcurementData

```
 public class ProcurementData
    {
        public ProcurementData()
        {
            this.PurchaseObjects = new List<PurchaseObject>();
            this.Customers = new List<Customer>();
            this.PublicationDate = new DateTime();
            this.EndDate = new DateTime();
            this.AuctionDate = new DateTime();
        }

        [Key]
        public string Number { set; get; }
        public string Name { set; get; }
        public double InitialCost { set; get; }

        public DateTime PublicationDate { set; get; }
        public DateTime EndDate { set; get; }
        public DateTime AuctionDate { set; get; }
        public string ApplicanterName { set; get; }

        public virtual ICollection<Customer> Customers { set; get; }

        public virtual ICollection<PurchaseObject> PurchaseObjects { set; get; }


    }
```

## Customer

```
public class Customer
    {
        public Customer()
        {
            this.ProcurementData = new List<ProcurementData>();
            this.PurchaseObjects = new List<PurchaseObject>();
        }
        [Key]
        public string Name { set; get; }

        public string INN { set; get; }

        public string KPP { set; get; }
        public virtual ICollection<ProcurementData> ProcurementData { set; get; }
        public virtual ICollection<PurchaseObject> PurchaseObjects { set; get; }

    }
```

### PurchaseObject

```
  public class PurchaseObject
    {
        public int Id { set; get; }
        public string Name { set; get; }
        public string OKPD2Code { set; get; }
        public string MeasurementType { set; get; }
        public double Amount { set; get; }
        public double UnitPrice { set; get; }
        public double TotalPrice { set; get; }

        public string CustomerName { get; set; }

        public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }

        public virtual ProcurementData ProcurementData { get; set; }
    }
```

### DBContext

```
public class MyDbcontext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<ProcurementData> ProcurementData { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PurchaseObject> PurchaseObjects { get; set; }

        public MyDbcontext() : base(nameOrConnectionString: "Default")
        {
            Database.CreateIfNotExists();
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<PurchaseObject>()
                .HasRequired(p => p.ProcurementData)
                .WithMany(p => p.PurchaseObjects);


            modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
                .HasMany(p => p.PurchaseObjects);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ProcurementData>()
                .HasMany(c => c.Customers)
                .WithMany( p => p.ProcurementData);

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many to many relationships requires one extra table... Think about it.

Edit: If you want a bit of theory about relational DDBBs design begin here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

Continue with 2NF, 3... etc

Keeping it simple: if you have a `ICollection<Customer>` in `ProcurementData` and a `ICollection<ProcurementData>` in `Customer` you need a table storing the relationship Id-Id.

Comment: Thanks! I will read it. Your and Stefan's answers led to (it seems to me) the reason for the emptiness of this table. The table really should be. I implemented these relationships between entities for the general case, but at the moment I do not use all the features. In particular, when parsing I do not enter information about in which offer a particular customer participates (on Customer side). Only in the ProcurementData, I fill out the list of customers. I do not know how correct this approach is? To be honest, this is my first experience with databases.

Comment: @Pavel: as for your question: if you anticipate that you'll need this relation in the near future, you should keep it. If not, you can remove it. Since this is your first attemt; its likely changes will come. EF provides nice funtionality for migrations so that will be easy. Even if you're well experienced you'll find yourself needing to change the model now and then, so dont worry about mistakes, its part of the development process;-)

Comment: @Stefan, I tried, but my reputation is lower than 15 (I recently registered), so my vote is only taken into account, but not displayed (according to the pop-up message :-) )

Answer (score 1):

Its a join (many to many) table because you have a list of `Customers` in yoy `ProcurementData` *and* visa versa.

You should keep it or reconsider your data model.

Comment: Thanks!  Your and DrkDeveloper's answers led to (it seems to me) the reason for the emptiness of this table. The table really should be. I implemented these relationships between entities for the general case, but at the moment I do not use all the features. In particular, when parsing I do not enter information about in which offer a particular customer participates (on Customer side). Only in the ProcurementData, I fill out the list of customers. I do not know how correct this approach is? To be honest, this is my first experience with databases.